# Specific vacation type for a lonely hike?

Tags: hiking, vacations

I'm playing with the idea of taking a whole week off of civilization. I imagine something like a long trail, that will take about a week to clear with as little contact to other people as possible.

On the other hand I'm not familiar with survival or outdoor activities in the slightest, which is why I'm asking for some kind of packaged experience.

Is there a term for this type of vacation?

Nice to have:

- Opportunity to cut the trail short, like a bus station every 50km
- Environment that is easy to survive in (no wild animals, cabins to sleep in)

I feel like my want of solitude but comfort are somewhat contradictory.

EDIT: While there might not be a term for that type of vacation, I'm thankful for the great suggestions and the concern about my fitness of even trying it out :)

Comment: Hiking holiday?

Comment: I'm not an outdoors expert but I think you're looking for a *trek* with *huts* or *refuges* along the trail.

Comment: I would honestly suggest, simply go and stay *in a hotel* in hiking country, in say Switzerland or Austria.  (A "remote" part of same.)  You can get up early, hike all day, hardly see a soul - and when the sun goes down you can relax in a real hotel with a sauna, etc. You'll get your fill of remote.  (Note - winter is here, so you're stuffed for now.)

Comment: _"I imagine something like a long trail, that will take about a week to clear with as little contact to other people as possible. On the other hand I'm not familiar with survival or outdoor activities in the slightest"_ What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: If you have no experience of outdoors, 50km might be as much as 5 days by foot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you live in Europe, I think mountain hiking in Andorra may be something fitting your needs.

I've been there for a few days several years ago. The mountains are quite remote, there are no crowds, but if for any reason you need to go back to civilization, you just go down and villages are not far away as Andorra is a very small country. There's a system of "refugio" - unmanned mountain huts maintained by government, which are open to everyone and free to use. When I've been there we spent 4 nights at refugios and only once met other people sleeping in the same hut (it was in July). A week should allow you to go the full round and maybe also see a bit of Pyrenees at French or Spanish side, depending on how much time every day you want to spend hiking.

You can find more on refugios here: http://www.hola-andorra.com/arinsal/english/refugisGB.html

To get to Andorra, I think it's best to fly to Barcelona (budget airlines connection to multiple European cities) and then take a bus to Andorra.

Comment: Indeed, I think there's no term for this so formally the question has no answer (and should be closed?). Still I prefer to give an answer which while technically a bit incorrect, might end up useful :)

Comment: @pnuts Agreed but when the question starts talking about it being nice to have a bus station every 50km and so on, the scope starts to look like more than just "what's the name for this"?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept your answer. My private life very suddenly didn't allow for it anymore, so I forgot about the question.

Answer (score 5):

I would call it a solo hiking holiday.

This time go for a well used and well sign posted trail, like one of the many in England, France or even the Netherlands (almost no hills but many long distance routes.) All these routes have hotels, hostels, huts and/or campsites with cabins.
Or something like that in whatever country you live.
There are even tours like this where they transport your luggage for you.

When walking alone you might see others, you usually do just say 'good day' and go on with your own things. But walking where there are no others is not good for a first solo tour, as you do not yet know where your limits are and how to get hold of help when you did bite off more than you can swallow.
Going up into the mountains of Andorra will be great when you have more experience, not for a first trip alone.

Answer (score 4):

Depending where you are, and the level of solitude and comfort you want.

Two that comes to mind:

Compostelle Route: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camino_de_Santiago_(route_descriptions)

Appalachian Trail: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_Trail

Comment: And you will see LOTS of people on Camino de Santiago!

Answer (score 3):

The old post route between Tokyo and Kyoto might be a good choice. Large parts of it are in woods, but there are small villages along the route that have guest houses (ryokan) where you can take a hot bath and stay overnight. For example, the route passes through the Kiso valley near [Tsumago](https://www.google.com/search?q=tsumago&tbm=isch) (the stairs you can see on some of the pictures is in the middle of the main street, so there is no traffic through the town).

This definitely needs some preparation though:

- planning the route with daily stops, and alternative paths for longer/shorter walks
- reserving rooms
- learning enough Japanese to ask for directions and follow table manners

You won't be entirely alone for the trip, but people are unlikely to talk to you without a reason. Dinner in a ryokan is normally together with the owner and the other guests, and you can usually get a lunch packet there as well.

Comment: Is that the Tokaido?

Comment: No, it's on a more direct line (not along the coast, but farther inland).